# Spheric equation to Cartesian equation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates

I have this equation $$\rho^2=2 \sin(2\theta)\cos(\phi)$$ and I want to convert it into a Cartesian equation. I’ve already applied an trigonometric identity and I have this$$\rho^2=4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)$$ and I don’t know what else to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, that you have following spherical coordinates:
$x=r \sin \phi \cos \theta$, $y=r \sin \phi \sin \theta$, $z = r \cos \phi$

From these we have $$y^2+z^2=r^2\sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta + r^2 \cos^2 \phi=\\=r^2\left( \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta +1- \sin^2 \phi \right)=r^2\left( 1+ \sin^2 \phi \left(\sin^2 \theta -1 \right) \right)= r^2 \big(1- \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi \big) \ \ \ (1)$$ 
and 
$$x^2 + y^2=r^2\sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \theta + r^2\sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta=r^2 \sin^2 \phi \ \ \ (2)$$

Your equation is possible to write as
$$r^4=16\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\cos^2(\phi) = 16(1- \cos^2 \theta)\cos^2 \theta (1-\sin^2 \phi)$$

Then we will have equation in $x,y,z$. Happy simplification.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to simplify the $$16(1-\cos^2(\theta))\cos^2(\theta)(1-\sin^2(\phi)$$ using the things you write on the third line

Comment: Yes. But from second line: there are expression for $\sin^2 \phi$ and $\cos^2 \theta$. And don't  forget to take it together with left side.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding that part

Comment: May be because I had mistake in one part. Sorry. Corrected and wrote steps to make understandable.

Comment: I'm still not understanding how you get the things you put on $x^2+y^2$ and $y^2+z^2$

Comment: I added numeration. So you mean (1) and (2)? If yes, then I simply took definition for spherical coordinates from 1-st line and created sum of squares.

Comment: Yes I get the first equalities, the second ones are the ones I'm not understanding

Comment: Added more steps to second one.

Comment: You're amazing thank you

Comment: Have you success in simplification?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm still stuck in the simplification

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/

Comment: Will that calc help me simplify it?

Comment: There is exactly "simplify" button, which can be helpful.